# How to convert logback-spring.xml to spring.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I'm trying to migrate a spring boot application to native, but the documentation says:

> Logback is supported, but not configuration with logback.xml so please configure it with application.properties or application.yml
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle

My file `src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />

    <springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="br.com.mycompany" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

There's a way to provide this same configurations with application.properties?

Comment: this url should help you. https://springframework.guru/using-yaml-in-spring-boot-to-configure-logback/

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?